# Google API Scope: What's the difference between email and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read

Tags: google-api

For the Google API Scope, 
access to user's email 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope
has been deprecated according to https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email

So the new scope is "email" instead of the long url.

But what is the difference between scopes
"email" and "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`email` gives you access to the authenticated users Google email address e.g. `name@gmail.com`.

```
"emails": [
  {
   "value": "name@gmail.com",
   "type": "account"
  }
 ]
```

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read` gives you access to all public email addresses on the users profile that they have verified.

```
"emails": [
  {
   "value": "name@gmail.com",
   "type": "account"
  },
  {
   "value": "name@gmail.com",
   "type": "home"
  },
  {
   "value": "name@example.com",
   "type": "home"
  }
 ]
```

Comment: So does it mean that the second  one is covering the first scope?  Or  the second cannot access user's email address?

Comment: The documentation is a great source of knowledge. "the user's Google account email address, as well as any public, verified email addresses in the user's Google+ profile."

Comment: Yep. I was actually using plusDomains API. I requested the domain admin to add https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profiles.read scopes to my service account but haven't got it working yet. When I test the plusDomains API  people.get method, scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile( deprecated and replaced by "email") and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profiles.read is enough to retrieve data. So I am wondering in this case, if I could use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read instead of email.

Comment: AFAIK those email scopes only work for uses requesting their own info authenticated as themselves.

Comment: That's correct. But say if you want to get others plus info who are in the same domain with you using plusDomains API, (Assuming you are a Google Enterprise Apps User), you will need these email scopes as well. This makes sense because they need to know what domain you are in by looking at your email address at first.

Comment: Yes you will need the scopes but the requests have to be made authenticated as the user, not as a service account. In which case you only need the `email` scope as their Google Apps email is always returned.