# Google sign in permission "See and download all of your Google Account email addresses""

Tags: google-signin

Need to understand what does the sign in permission of google sign in means when I select one of the email address and then get an on screen message like "See and download all of your Google Account email addresses" ?

Is that implies to see and download permission for all my Contacts or some thing else.

Can some one clarify me.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short Answer

It gives the website *"access to all public email addresses on the users profile that they have verified"* ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829066/google-api-scope-whats-the-difference-between-email-and-https-www-googleapis)). In other words, it just shows the website your GMail address.

---

#### Long Answer

When I was linking my Google account to another website, the pop-up URL ended with this:

```
...&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.profile.emails.read&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

which decodes to this:

```
...&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

The [answer I linked to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829066/google-api-scope-whats-the-difference-between-email-and-https-www-googleapis) explains that `auth/plus.profile.emails.read` gives the website *"access to all public email addresses on the users profile that they have verified"*. The Google API returns this to the website:

```
"emails": [
  {
   "value": "name@gmail.com",
   "type": "account"
  },
  {
   "value": "name@gmail.com",
   "type": "home"
  },
  {
   "value": "name@example.com",
   "type": "home"
  }
 ]
```

So I wonder how you can have multiple email addresses linked with one Google account? I can't find evidence that it's possible. And the 'plus' in the API search makes me think this is some legacy thing from the days of Google Plus. The [Google OAuth 2.0 page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#people) does offer `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read` but there's no sign of 'plus'. And it just describes that endpoint as 'View your email addresses', which again is vague.